# FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count:

Tags: filter, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have been using these 2 queries to fetch data in 2 different sheets

```
=query('Raw Data'!A3:P62481,"select B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P where B = date '"&text($B$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)

=sort(unique(FILTER('Raw Data'!$A:$P,'Raw Data'!$G:$G=$C$1,'Raw Data'!$B:$B=$F$1)))
```

Looking for a way to combine both. And get output in one single sheet, get data for specific DATE and C1.

Please help!

Already tried this:

```
=sort(unique(FILTER('Raw Data'!$A:$P,'Raw Data'!$G:$G=$C$1, QUERY(query('Raw Data'!A3:P62481,"select B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P where B = date '"&text($B$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)))))

=sort(unique(FILTER(QUERY('Raw Data'!$A:$P,"select B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P where B = date '"&text($F$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1,'Raw Data'!$G:$G=$C$1))))
```

> Error FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 2745.
> column count: 1. Actual row count: 62481, column count: 1.
>
> Link to the sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymFGf9eNzCoWHLwLjolQliOMBwswgaPP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check out [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126192/filter-has-mismatched-range-size-referencing-the-second-last-cell-in-a-column-i) for a more well-rounded solution for matching  the range sizes for filter(), or [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/96065/google-sheets-filter-conditions-from-list) solution using match() which may be much simpler depending on what you are trying to do

Comment: Link to the sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymFGf9eNzCoWHLwLjolQliOMBwswgaPP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

in your first formula, the output is **14** columns while in your 2nd formula the output is **16** columns. there is no way how to combine it unless you have equal column count in the matrix. one of the ways would be adding two fake columns in the query like:

```
={QUERY('Raw Data'!A3:P62481, 
 "select B,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,' ','  ' 
  where B = date '"&TEXT($B$1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  label '  ''','  '''", 1);
  SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER('Raw Data'!$A:$P, 'Raw Data'!$G:$G=$C$1, 'Raw Data'!$B:$B=$F$1)))}
```